# How do I diagnose configparser not working under pydev

Tags: python-3.x, pydev

My question is: How do I diagnose this?  I'm learning PyDev and Python so I want to know how to get to the answer, not just the answer.

The background is:

I have an application that uses configparser and executes fine under IDLE/3.8, but not under PyDev. The symptom is that all configparser calls result in zero data. It looks like the object is blank.
The first error I get occurs when I try and use the parser output. It is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Projects\ActiveWindow\ActiveWindow\StickyWindow.py", line 154, in <module>
    sticky_window = config['base']['window_name']
  File "C:\Users\Rich\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\configparser.py", line 960, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'base'
```

Where 'base' is one of the section names. It is the first and only section after 'DEFAULT'

Version Info:

```
 Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers

 Version: 2019-06 (4.12.0)
 Build id: 20190614-1200

 PyDev for Eclipse  7.5.0.202001101138
```

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment you can offer.

The salient code section is:

```
    ###########################################################################
    #    Read a Config file if we have one or write a default one if we don't
    ###########################################################################

    config = configparser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)

    if os.path.isfile('StickyWindow.cfg'):
        config.read('StickyWindow.cfg')

    ###########################################################################
    #   default config comment lines use extra white space to make them 
    #   different so that they actually make it into the config file
    ###########################################################################
    else:
        config['DEFAULT'] = {
            '############################################################################' : None,
            '#' : None,
            '#  Config file for StickyWindow.py' : None,
            '#  ' : None,
            '#  Do not use trailing comments in lines' : None,
            '#   ' : None,
            '#  Add new configuration settings to the [base] section using the same' : None,
            '#  names as the [DEFAULT] section' : None,
            '#    ' : None,
            '############################################################################ ' : None,
            ' ' : None,
            'loop_delay' : '0.5',
            'keystrokes' : '',
            'hot_key' : 'ctrl+shift+q',
            '  ' : None,
            '############################################################################  ' : None,
            '# To remove window names from the window listing, add them in single' : None,
            '# quotes to window_name_suppress separated by commas inside square brackets' : None,
            '############################################################################   ' : None,
            '   ' : None,
            'window_name_suppress' : ['','MSCTFIME UI','Default IME',
            'Window','Settings','Microsoft Store','G','MyTimerMsgWnd'],
            'stable_mouse_threshold' : '3'
            }    
        config['base'] = {
            '############################################################################   ' : None,
            '#     ' : None,
            '#  Do not use quotes around window name' : None,
            '#      ' : None,
            '############################################################################    ' : None,
            '    ' : None,
            'window_name' : sticky_window}
        print('write config')
        with open('stickywindow.cfg',
                  'w') as configfile: config.write(configfile)

    ###########################################################################
    #    Command line window name overrides config file specification
    ###########################################################################

    if (len(sticky_window) == 0):
        sticky_window = config['base']['window_name']

    loop_delay = config.getfloat('base','loop_delay')
    keystrokes = config['base']['keystrokes']
    window_name_suppress = config['base']['window_name_suppress']
    mouse_count_threshold = int(config['base']['stable_mouse_threshold'])
```

Oz (in DFW)

Answer (score 0):

My guess by looking at the code is that:

`if os.path.isfile('StickyWindow.cfg'):` is returning `False` and then the config is not read.

This is probably because your working directory is not the same when you're running in PyDev vs when you're running in IDLE.

So, use the full filepath to load it (if you want to make it relative to the current file, you can probably use `__file__` -- otherwise it should probably be received as an argument or environment variable).